# Calculator in php without switch

Tags: php

I am new in php, I have 3 arguments in a function

```
function cal($x,$y,$op){
$z=$x.$op.$y;
return $z;
}
echo cal(3,4,'/');
```

And I also try this:

```
$z=$x$op$y;
```

and I am getting `3/4` as answer but I want `0.75`

Comment: That's because right now you are just building a string..

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function cal($x,$y,$op){
$z=$x.$op.$y;
return calculate_string($z);
}
echo cal(3,4,'/');

function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
    $mathString = trim($mathString);     // trim white spaces
    $mathString = ereg_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString);    // remove any non-numbers chars; exception for math operators

    $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
    return 0 + $compute();
}
```